# how to fix the height of a tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, font-size, fixed

Recently I have written a custom `UITableViewCell` with a height of 60.0f.  When it runs on different device, such as `iPhone5`  `iPhone6` `iPhone6 +`, the height and `fontSize` changes automatically. How to fix the height?

```
  - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
        reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if (!self) {
            return nil;
        }       
        self.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        self.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
        self.detailTextLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        self.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
        self.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        _switchButton = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 9, 30, 20)];
        _switchButton.tag = 400;
        [_switchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(switchAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:_switchButton];

        _button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        _button.frame = CGRectMake(250, 9, 60, 30);
        [_button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:_button];
        _button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        return self;
    }
```

in the controller:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 60.0;
}
```

Comment: Show the tableview creation code please, probably you need to change rowHeight of UITableView to be 60.0f not UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: sorry, here are the creations:

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 60.0;
}

Answer (score 0):

Set the `self.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines` to exact value, not 0. This will turn off automatic sizing for label.

Comment: Then try to not use textLabel and detailTextLabel from UITableViewCell. Set up your own labels in your own properties.